# Whats the difference of CURL request and from an HTML form?

Tags: php

I'am making a POST request from the server and there is an option to make requests from the HTML form, the other server that accepts it, cant handle 20 request from the server, but how he will know if it is a USER sended post(from browser I mean) or from the server using CURL...is there any difference? for example even if I set the user agent, to make it act like a real user?

Comment: There is no difference. It's all HTTP requests. You are able to "fake" all data send in a HTML form with cURL (user agents, cookies, POST data, GET data, headers, etc. etc.). There's no way you can tell if the request *actually* came from the browser. The only way you can get unique data is if the client making the HTTP request is different (eg. different computers/devices/servers).

Comment: If you try hard you can make the entire request the same. Only the IP address will be different, and I'm not sure if you can spoof that through cUrl.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any hard differences, just different *default* headers (the source IP address might also be a factor).

Answer (score 0):

With curl, you are able to fake a real user and make him look like a random visitor by altering settings like user agent, sent headers and so on.

They might check the request ip, which you can fake by using a combination of tor and privoxy, which acts as a proxy server for you and will change your ip.